# Check given date exists between 2 date fields in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have table which contains 2 date fields. Like:

```
id      from             to
---     ----             --
1       2012-01-01       2012-01-05
2       2012-01-04       2012-01-10
3       2012-01-03       2012-01-07
```

I want to use a date (ex: 2012-01-06) to check if the date is between any of the dates(from, to) in the table.

For this case, I want to get id - 2,3. how can I do this?

Comment: Are these columns of type `date`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE "2012-01-06" BETWEEN `from` and `to`
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `from` <= "2012-01-06" AND "2012-01-06" <= `to`
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html

Answer (score 2):

```
select id 
from myTable 
where `from` <= '2012-01-06' and `to` >= '2012-01-06'
```

Comment: Actually I was trying this. but the field names were "from" and "to". I was not using tilde "`". so, this is was the problem. but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Apply this condition if the column types are `date`.

```
WHERE '2012-01-06' BETWEEN `from` AND `to`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from Table where `from` < '2012-01-06' and `to` > '2012-01-06'
```